# Cannot see the whole information from my database in a text field if i have a space in my text

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textfield, space

I have problem in my site, to be more specific in my edit pages and especially in my edit textfields it does not shows the whole information in the textfields.

As you can see in the images, in the text fields it does not shows the whole information.

[image]

I want to show it like I have it in the database.

[image]

Ignore the first row...

Here is my code...

```
<?php
            $username = $_SESSION["username"];

        if(isset($_POST['id'])){

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
            $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["city"]);
            $phone = ($_POST["phone"]);

            $query="UPDATE personal_information
                    SET name = '$name', email = '$email', city = '$city', phone='$phone'
                    WHERE id='$id'";

            mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_affected_rows()>=0){
                echo "<p>($username) Record Updated<p>";
            }else{
                echo "<p>($username) Not Updated<p>";
            }
        }

        else{
          //first time, initialize as you wish. Probably need to get the first id for this user, using another query
          $id = 0;
        }

        if($query = mysql_query("SELECT name,email,city,phone FROM personal_information WHERE id>'$id' AND username='$username' order by id asc limit 1") or die(mysql_error()))
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $city = $row['city'];
                $phone = $row['phone'];
                }
            }
            else{
                echo 'No entry found. <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>';
            }
        }

        ?>
```

HTML FORM CODE...

```
<form method="post" action="edit_personal_information.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
        <legend style="color: #F87F25; font: bold 18px Tahoma;">Personal Information</legend>
        <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 12px Tahoma;">Name <input type="text" name="name" value=<?=$name?> required="required" /> </label>
        <br /><br />
        <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 12px Tahoma;">Email <input type="text" name="email" value=<?=$email?> required="required"/> </label>
        <br /><br />
        <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 12px Tahoma;">City <input type="text" name="city" value=<?=$city?> /> </label>
        <br /><br />
        <label style="color: #01ACEE; font: bold 12px Tahoma;">Phone <input type="text" name="phone" value=<?=$phone?> /> </label>
        <br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id2" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 0 : $id );?>" style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="update" name="submit" style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;"/>
    </form>
```

I can understand that the problem is that it cannot display the spaces between the text but I cant find a solution to that

Comment: before $name = $row['name']; add a die($row['name']); to see what you re actullaly gettign out of the DB that way you can see if it;s the DB problem or the HTML.

Comment: @Horaland I did that you said and I just get the first name which is Nikos

Comment: @CoDeMurDeRer edited in order to see the html form code

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the information from the right record? `id>'$id'` seems a very odd thing to add to your `SELECT` statement...

Comment: @jeroen yes i am sure the problem is not the id, i am using the id in order to make it unique, it is a compination of a primary key with the username, which you cant see it in the image because i didnt print screen it the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value=<?=$name?>
```

If the name has a space, the resulting HTML will be:

```
value=Foo Bar
```

Which means the value is only `Foo`, "Bar" becomes an unrelated second attribute.
You need to take care to produce proper HTML syntax:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>"
```

Also read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).